# PHP floats precision causing error when adding

Tags: php

Here is a simplified version of my problem. Here is a for loop:

```
for ($i = 0.01; $i < 100; $i += 0.01) {
    echo $i;
}
```

At some point, `i` might output 51.189999999998. This creates two problems. Firstly, I cannot detect whether a number is a whole number or a decimal using the `fmod` or `strpos`. And secondly, it affects the readability of the output.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

Comment: No, if you think they are errors then you don't understand at all. And if you read the content at the link I provided it describes how to get the result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Count in numbers with integer values in floating-point type. I am unfamiliar with PHP and the [documentation](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) is unclear (it shows an `LNUM` grammer object for floating-point literals that overlaps integer literals without saying how they are distinguished), but this may work:

```
for ($i = 1.; $i < 10000.; $i += 1.) {
    $t = $i * .01;
    echo $t;
}
```

Note that, in PHP, the characteristics of the floating-point type may vary. On systems that use IEEE 754 basic 64-bit binary floating point, you can count in integer values up to 2<sup>53</sup> before rounding errors occur in the counting.

Comment: @WeavingBird1917: You said in the question “I also tried to make always increment i by one, … however there would be a point where i exceeds the 32 bit max integer.” This makes it seem like you incremented `$i` as an **integer type**, which is different from using an **integer value** in a **floating-point type**. A 32-bit integer type would overflow at 2\*\*32. The IEEE-754 floating-point type would not overflow representable integers until 2\*\*53.